# Survfit counting death again in subsequent timepoints for the same individual

Tags: uniqueidentifier, survival-analysis, data-wrangling

I am trying to analyse a dataset that is currently in long format.
The data set has a set of individuals that are marked  as either alive (0) or dead (1) at each timepoint.
After running my code I realized that it is counting multiple instances of 1 (death) for each timepoint, rather than just the first timepoint in which the individual has an entry of 1.
This means my survival is coming out lower than it should as it is treating each timepoint for an individual as a separate individual entirely.
Is there a way to specify that individuals should stop being considered after the first entry of 1 (dead)?

Goals:
An individual should only contribute to n.event once.
n.risk should reflect the number of individuals still alive, and not the total number of data entries.

```
da <- data.frame(userid = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4), day= c(1,7,18,1,7,18,1,7,18,1,7,18), status = c(0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1), Treat =c(1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0))

km_fit <- survfit(Surv(day, status) ~ interaction(Treat), data = da)

summary(km_fit)
```

[Layout of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1H8F.jpg)
[Readout of summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2C6Z6.jpg)

My actual data has 9 (counted in days from t=0 rather than actual dates) timepoints and thousands of individuals.
I have tried to find a simplified way to pull time-to-event data out of my current format and have not had much luck.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.